# Can I detect instruction set architecture in vimrc? (ARM vs x86)

Tags: vim, cpu-architecture

I sometimes develop code on ARM hardware (Cubietruck or Rpi) as their dire slowness helps me to find code bottlenecks more easily than on amd64. However I want Vim to remain responsive so I need to turn a few things off depending on which architecture I'm running on (cursorline in particular is very resource intensive). How can I detect underlying architecture from my vimrc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about if you use `system()` to call `uname -m` and check your Kernel architecture?

```
if system("uname -m") == "armv7l\n"
  set foo
  set bar
endif
```

Fix suggested at the comments to add `\n` at the comparsion string, since `uname -m` will add a newline after the command is executed.

Comment: nice. Since I occasionally use windows or OSX too I'll nest it in a check for Linux.

Comment: Sounds good. You could nest an `uname` as higher level to find the OS, and another to match the architecture if that is the case :) - But for matching OS, you could use `has()` if you intend to also check if the Operating System you are using is Windows - https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/detect-os-in-vimscript

Comment: unfortunately I just stuck this in my vimrc with set nocursorline and it doesn't seem to work :-(  .... how can I debug it see what this is returning?

Comment: `vim -V9vimlog.log` where `-V[number]` is the log level you want... Just don't know if the runtime log will also tell error about things not being executed on `.vimrc`

Comment: @nwilder aha! I think I fixed the problem. system(uname -m) returns a newline afterwards so you must test for "aarmv71\n". If you change the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice catch! Added to the answer. Good you have figured out this little newline bastard :D